# Double the RAM consumed than the file size on disk

Tags: windows, memory, visual-c++, mfc, ram

I am opening a huge txt file (~ 350 MB) in Notepad++
When I am monitoring the Private Bytes consumed for Notepad++ before and after opening the file, I see approx. 730 MB consumed where as the file that is opened is just around 350 MBs.

I am not trying to point problem with Notepad++ as I see same memory consumption when I write data of this file to my MFC CEditCtrl too. I need to know as to why this behavior.

PS: I monitor Private Bytes using Process Explorer software.

Comment: Maybe because Notepad++ stores each character as a wide character.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Like is said in my post, it has nothing to do with Notepad++
I tried the same with my MFC application and tried opening in WordPad too but the same behavior is noticed. 
I want to know why is the memory in RAM consumed almost double of the actual file size ?

Comment: Don't make your question complicated. If it has nothing to do with Notepad++ then don't mention Notepad++. `CEdit` uses wide char, so it needs twice as many bytes if the file is ASCII. Notepad++ probably saves files in UTF-8 which can end in similar result.

Comment: Wordpad probably also characters as wide char and so does the Windows edit control.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thanks. This helped. The fact that my CEdit consumes double the memory is because of usage of Wide characters.